# formatting string using thymeleaf function

Tags: java, thymeleaf

im trying to format view template using thymeleaf, I'm passing to the view layer, as "timeList":

```
private static final String[] visitTime = 
        {"9:00:00","9:30:00","10:00:00","10:30:00","11:00:00","11:30:00","12:00:00",
                "12:30:00","13:00:00","13:30:00","14:00:00","14:30:00","15:00:00","15:30:00","16:00:00","16:30:00"};
```

now In view I'd like to have it displayed as HH:MM for e.g. 14:30.

this is my form:

```
<label for="time">Time:</label>
            <select name="time">
                <option th:each="time : ${timeList}" th:value="${time}"  th:text="${numbers.format(num,3,'POINT'}" ></option>
            </select>
```

I was trying to use some of number class functions but without success.

Answer (score 2):

The dates.format method should work with the `HH:mm` pattern

```
<label for="time">Time:</label>
  <select name="time">
    <option th:each="time : ${timeList}" th:value="${time}"
      th:text="${#dates.format(time,'HH:mm')}">
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf exposes a special object, beans, to let you access all Spring beans in the current application context.

Let’s define a dateFormatter bean as follow:

```
<bean id="dateFormatter" class="doan.thymeleaf.demo.util.DateFormatter"/>
```

The source code of the bean is quite straightforward:

```
public class DateFormatter
{
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public String getCurrentDate()
    {
        return new DateTime(new Date()).toString(DATE_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

This bean defines a public getCurrentDate() method we’ll use in our page.

```
<span th:text="${'Current date is : '+beans.dateFormatter.getCurrentDate()}">Current date is : 2012-04-14 17:30:00</span>
```

To access our bean named `“dateFormatter“`, we have to use the helper object “beans” provided by Thymeleaf. Under the hood beans is simply a Map which contains all references to the beans registered in the Spring context. There is really no magic here.

### Resource Location:

1. [ThymeLeaf advanced usage](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/spring-mvc-part-iv-thymeleaf-advanced-usage/)